# How to access OneDrive when using the Web Account Manager?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, onedrive

Okay, so I used

```
WebTokenRequest webTokenRequest =
    new WebTokenRequest(Provider, Scope, ClientID);

WebTokenRequestResult _result =
    await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(webTokenRequest);

string id = _result.ResponseData[0].WebAccount.ID;
string token = _result.ResponseData[0].Token;
```

...to get the the token needed to access the user's OneDrive account. The sign in went well and all, but now what API am I to use to start accessing OneDrive with that token and key I received?

There is absolutely NO documentation to help novices out beyond this point. Whatsoever. In fact, there isn't a human that discusses anything beyond getting the token. All of the documentation and videos simply tell you how to log the users in and get the token, etc.. But now I need to start working with the OneDrive account of the user who I just logged into my app... Any help on where to begin. The ONLY thing I need is a starting point. I will read and learn for myself at that point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to work with the OneDrive SDK you can use [this example code](https://github.com/ginach/Simple-IAuthenticationProvider-sample-for-OneDrive-SDK) to initialize a OneDriveClient using the access token you retrieved. After retrieving an authenticated client you might want to look at the [SDK documentation](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp) for some of the high-level concepts of working with the SDK. For the most part, the calling patterns closely mirror the [API URL calling patterns](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm).

If your goal isn't to work with the SDK you can craft calls against the API endpoint directly. You'll want to add the token to the Authorization header as "Authorization: bearer token". Take a look at the [API documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm) for the specific functionality of the OneDrive API.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. I will definitely look into the documentation.